# How to create a Login based app using LUA?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Can anyone help me in creating a login based app in LUA and corona sdk. I have used database like sqlite and mysql but it is not working as intended. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to show which part of your code is not working so that a help can be extended.

Comment: Please go through the basics, follow tutorials and build a foundation. This might be a good start: https://docs.coronalabs.com/tutorial/#tutorials SO is not a platform to get the free code. Show us what have you done so far,  where you are stuck, Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply macroland and wsha.

Comment: How can i upload my code here?

Comment: here is a part of my code where when user click submit button then the values enter by the user in the text field get stored in the database.

local function handleButtonEvent( event )
{{       if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
      local tablefill = [[INSERT INTO Mobile VALUES (']]..defaultBox..[[',']]..NumberBox..[[',']]..EmailBox..[['); ]]

   print( "Button was pressed and released" )
   end
end
}}

Comment: I have just now figure out. Thanks guys